# Type error :a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in create_signed_url(url,keypairid)? boto 2.42

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto, amazon-cloudfront

```
def upload():
    conn=boto.connect_s3(AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID,AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,host=REGION_HOST)

    distribution = Distribution(connection=conn, config=None, domain_name='', id='', last_modified_time=None, status='')

    objurl="cloudfront url to my image in s3 bucket"
    url = distribution.create_signed_url(url=objurl, keypair_id=KEYPAIR_ID)
```

Error:

```
Type error :a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Using: boto 2.42, Python 3.5